# mustache.js: Enumerable objects with outer variable

Tags: javascript, mustache

Iv'e worked through [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/) great tutorial.

```
var data = {
    employees: [
    {   firstName: "Christophe",
        lastName: "Coenraets"},
    {   firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith"}
    ]}; 
var template = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}" +
                            "<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>" +
                            "{{/employees}}</ul>"; 
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data); 
$('#sampleArea').html(html);
```

My question is how to iterate some property that belongs to the data object inside the employees object?

Here is an example, i want to print the `label` next to each one of the `employees` before the close of the `</li>` tag:

```
var data = {
    employees: 
    [{
        firstName: "Christophe",
        lastName: "Coenraets"
    }],
    label: "red"
};

var template = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}" +
                            "<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}" + 
                            "the label is: {{label}}" +
                            "</li>" +
                            "{{/employees}}</ul>";
```

but the above example will obviously would not work because `label` is a property of `data`, not of `employees`.

Comment: did you tried {{../label}} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this: use "../" to go one level higher

```
var template = "Employees:<ul>{{#employees}}" +
                            "<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}" + 
                            "the label is: {{../label}}" +
                            "</li>" +
                            "{{/employees}}</ul>";
```

another solution would be to render the whole node like that:

```
var template = "{{#data}}Employees:<ul>{{#data.employees}}" +
                                "<li>{{data.employees.firstName}} {{data.employees.lastName}}" + 
                                "the label is: {{data.label}}" +
                                "</li>" +
                                "{{/data.employees}}</ul>{{/data}}"
```

Comment: given the second solution, is the {{#employees}} should be written as:  {{#data.employees}} also? and the {{firstName}} -> {{data.employees.firstName}}?

Comment: great answer! tnx